# What is the role of gl_Position.w in Vulkan?

Tags: glsl, vulkan

Variable `gl_Position` output from a GLSL vertex shader must have 4 coordinates. In OpenGL, it seems `w` coordinate is used to scale the vector, by dividing the other coordinates by it. What is the purpose of `w` in Vulkan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shaders and projections in Vulkan behave exactly the same as in OpenGL. There are small differences in depth ranges ([-1, 1] in OpenGL, [0, 1] in Vulkan) or in the origin of the coordinate system (lower-left in OpenGL, upper-left in Vulkan), but the principles are exactly the same. The hardware is still the same and it performs calculations in the same way both in OpenGL and in Vulkan.

4-component vectors serve multiple purposes:

1. Different transformations (translation, rotation, scaling) can be
   represented in the same way, with 4x4 matrices.
2. Projection can also be represented with a 4x4 matrix.
3. Multiple transformations can be combined into one 4x4 matrix.
4. The `.w` component You mention is used during perspective projection.

All this we can do with 4x4 matrices and thus we need 4-component vectors (so they can be multiplied by 4x4 matrices). Again, I write about this because the above rules apply both to OpenGL and to Vulkan.

So for purpose of the `.w` component of the `gl_Position` variable - it is exactly the same in Vulkan. It is used to scale the position vector - during perspective calculations (projection matrix multiplication) original depth is modified by the original `.w` component and stored in the `.z` component of the `gl_Position` variable. And additionally, original depth is also stored in the `.w` component. After that (as a fixed-function step) hardware performs perspective division and divides position stored in the `gl_Position` variable by its `.w` component.

In orthographic projection steps performed by the hardware are exactly the same, but values used for calculations are different. So the perspective division step is still performed by the hardware but it does nothing (position is dived by 1.0).

Comment: "*There are small differences in depth ranges ([-1, 1] in OpenGL, [0, 1] in Vulkan)*" In OpenGL, this is an option as well, thanks to [clip-control in 4.5](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_clip_control.txt).

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it is the only one that mentions Vulkan specifically.

Answer (score 3):

`gl_Position` is a [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). The `w` component plays a role at perspective projection.

The projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points of the view on a scene, to 2D points on the viewport. It transforms from eye space to the clip space, and the coordinates in the clip space are transformed to the normalized device coordinates (NDC) by dividing with the `w` component of the clip coordinates ([Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide)).

At Perspective Projection the projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points in the world as they are seen from of a pinhole camera, to 2D points of the viewport. 
 The eye space coordinates in the camera frustum (a truncated pyramid) are mapped to a cube (the normalized device coordinates).

[image: Perspective Projection]

Perspective Projection Matrix:

```
r = right, l = left, b = bottom, t = top, n = near, f = far

2*n/(r-l)      0              0                0
0              2*n/(t-b)      0                0
(r+l)/(r-l)    (t+b)/(t-b)    -(f+n)/(f-n)    -1    
0              0              -2*f*n/(f-n)     0
```

When a [Cartesian coordinate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) in view space is transformed by the perspective projection matrix, then the the result is a [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). The `w` component grows with the distance to the point of view. This cause that the objects become smaller after the [Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide), if they are further away.

Answer (score 1):

In computer graphics, transformations are represented with matrices. If you want something to rotate, you multiply all its vertices (a vector) by a rotation matrix. Want it to move? Multiply by translation matrix, etc.

**tl;dr:** You can't describe translation along the z-axis with 3D matrices and vectors. You need at least 1 more dimension, so they just added a dummy dimension `w`. But things break if it's not 1, so keep it at 1 :P.

---

Anyway, now we begin with a quick review on matrix multiplication:

[image: Matrix multiplication]

You basically put `x` above `a`, `y` above `b`, `z` above `c`. Multiply the whole column by the variable you just moved, and sum up everything in the row.

So if you were to translate a vector, you'd want something like:

[image]

See how `x` and `y` is now translated by `az` and `bz`? That's pretty awkward though:

1. You'd have to account for how big `z` is whenever you move things (what if `z` was negative? You'd have to move in opposite directions. That's cumbersome as hell if you just want to move something an inch over...)
2. You can't move along the `z` axis. You'll never be able to fly or go underground

But, if you can make sure `z = 1` at **all times**:

[image]

Now it's much clearer that this matrix allows you to move in the x-y plane by `a`, and `b` amounts. Only problem is that you're conceptually levitating all the time, and you still can't go up or down. You can only move in 2D.

But you see a pattern here? With 3D matrices and 3D vectors, you can describe all the fundamental movements in 2D. So what if we added a 4th dimension?

[image]

Looks familiar. If we keep `w = 1` **at all times**:

[image]

There we go, now you get translation along all 3 axis. This is what's called homogeneous coordinates.

But what if you were doing some big & complicated transformation, resulting in `w != 1`, and there's no way around it? OpenGL (and basically any other CG system I think) will do what's called normalization: divide the resultant vector by the `w` component. I don't know enough to say exactly why ('cause scaling is a linear transformation?), but it has favorable implications (can be used in perspective transforms). Anyway, the translation matrix would actually look like:

[image]

And there you go, see how each component is shrunken by `w`, *then* it's translated? That's why `w` controls scaling.